# Typeface.createFromAsset vs. ResourcesCompat.getFont font-weight difference

Tags: android, android-typeface

**1.**
Setting the typeface of a TextView using Typeface.createFromAsset:

```
val typefaceAssets = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "fonts/custom_font.ttf")
tvLabel.typeface = typefaceAssets
```

Result
[screen dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRHHu.gif)

**2.** Setting the exact same typeface of a TextView using ResourcesCompat.getFont:

```
val typefaceResources = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.custom_font)
tvLabel.typeface = typefaceResources
```

Result
[screen dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7NcN.gif)

The font weight seem to differ slightly using the two methods Typeface.createFromAsset being the most accurate. I wonder why?